# group by on one column and get the max on other column

Tags: linux

is there any way we can do group by on first column and max on other column in linux

Sample Input:

```
Manoj|2020-01-01 01:00:00
Manoj|2020-02-01 01:00:00
Manoj|2020-03-01 01:00:00
Rajesh|2020-01-01 01:00:00
Rajesh|2020-05-01 01:00:00
Suresh|2020-04-01 01:00:00
```

Expected output

```
Manoj|2020-03-01 01:00:00
Rajesh|2020-05-01 01:00:00
Suresh|2020-04-01 01:00:00
```

I tried referring link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15397205/bash-script-find-max-group-by-and-sort-by-column but getting null value. any suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you match the displayed order, then so

```
sort -t'|' -k1,1 -k2r file | awk -F'|' '!D[$1]++'
```

If the displayed order does not matter, then so

```
sort -r file | awk -F'|' '!D[$1]++'
```

Here, the AWK command displays only the first unique values by the first field, so by sorting we achieve that the desired value is the highest in the group

Answer (score 1):

command

```
for i in `awk -F "|" '{if(!seen[$1]++)print $1}' filename`; do awk -v i="$i" '$0 ~ i {x=$0}END{print x}' filename; done
```

output

```
Manoj|2020-03-01 01:00:00
Rajesh|2020-05-01 01:00:00
Suresh|2020-04-01 01:00:00
```

Python

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import os
import re
z=open('outfile','w')
fin=[]
k=open('j.txt','r')
for m in k:
    d=m.split('|')[0]
    if d not in fin:
        fin.append(d.strip())

for p in fin:
    gg=[]
    g=re.compile(r'{0}'.format(p))
    y=open('j.txt','r')
    for b in y:
        if re.search(g,b):
            gg.append(b)
    z.write(gg[-1].strip())
    z.write('\n')
```

output

```
Manoj|2020-03-01 01:00:00
Rajesh|2020-05-01 01:00:00
Suresh|2020-04-01 01:00:00
```

Comment: @Praveen_Kumar_BS, one command: ```awk -F'|' 'BEGIN {PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"} $2 > D[$1] {D[$1]=$2} END {for(i in D) print i "|" D[i]}' file```

Comment: @Praveen thanks a lot for the reply.. In the same python code  how can i copy the output into other file  ?

Comment: @Ravi Updated the code

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
sort -t'|' -k2r file | sort -u -t'|' -k1,1
```

Output:

```
Manoj|2020-03-01 01:00:00
Rajesh|2020-05-01 01:00:00
Suresh|2020-04-01 01:00:00
```